# automapper, On Create action on the controller. Confused

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have everthing set for automapper to work. Attribute is working fine as
well and properly filling DTO. My Controller Create Action looks like below

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoMap(typeof(User), typeof(UserCreateDTO))]
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _repository.Create(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = user.UserId });
    }

    return View("Edit", user);
}
```

I have DataAnnotation set on User object which is my Entity object and is passed
to repository which is interface via implementation and using User object everywhere.

What I want to do is like below using same above code.

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoMap(typeof(User), typeof(UserCreateDTO))]
public ActionResult Create(UserCreateDTO userdto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         _repository.Create(userdto);

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = userdto.UserId });
    }

    return View("Edit", userdto);
}
```

Question:
My DataAnnotation are now on UserCreateDTO to limit what I want to validate.
Once validation passed than there is problem which is when I pass userdto to Create method which not allowing me
as User object is in the interface like below

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    IQueryable<User> GetAllUsers();

    User GetUserById(Guid id);

    void Create(User user);
    User Edit(User user);
    void Delete(User user);

    void Save();
}
```

I can not change all the code to replace UserCreateDTO in Interface and Repository and What if I have UserEditDTO/UserShowDTO.
How I solve this problem?. I have explained as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you map back to a user object before calling Create? You don't need to use the attributes. You can call Map directly.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserCreateDTO, User>();
var user = new user();
Mapper.Map<UserCreateDTO, User>(userdto, user);
```

Set the debugger to stop after the map call and check to make sure the values were copied in correctly.

Comment: Give me an example please in my above action method. Will be grateful. I am noob to automapper.

Comment: You can also move the call to create map to one place in the application by creating your own class inheriting AutoMapper.Profile and overriding Configure.

Comment: There's lot's of ways to do it. I was showing him the minimum needed to get it running.

Comment: CRice I have done all that you have said already for Mapper.CreateMap<UserCreateDTO, User>();
This mapping is smooth as Source has all the properties of Destination but again mapping Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserCreateDTO>(); as rboarman suggested is extra work as I have to mention IGNORE for the properties that are not from DTO to User. There must be simple approach to my problem?

Comment: Only ignore properties that have the same name. Ones that don't match will not cause a problem.